# Объясните авторизацию Restful

Tags: php, soap, rest

Не совсем ясно, как работает механизм на основе передачи секретного и публичного ключа.

Comment: Каждый сервис обычно реализует авторизацию по-своему. С каким вы сейчас работаете?

Comment: я пишу restful на php с 0. У каждого пользователя будет свой уникальный пароль, сгенерированный. без логина. Нужно один раз авторизировать и после дать доступ к использованию restful. Как это реализовывается? хранить toket авторизации в сессии для текущнго пользователя?

Comment: @IOleg [Криптосистема с открытым ключом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BC)

Answer (score 5):

[[@IOleg](/users/13437/ioleg)](/users/13437/ioleg), теперь вопрос куда яснее. Я так понимаю, вы создаете API, в этом случае сессии нельзя использовать - привязка клиент-сессия осуществляется через куки, ее можно имитировать через курл, но никто так не делает, слишком мног омороки с инвалидацией. Обычно создается секретный ключ, который знают только сервис и клиент; после этого с помощью секретного ключа создается подпись к каждому запросу, которая позволяет установить, что запрос

1. Действительно был послан тем клиентом, который указан в запросе
2. Все параметры запросы действительно прописаны оригинальным клиентом (запрос может быть перехвачен по пути, после чего в него можно напихать "своих" параметров, если этой проверки не будет)
3. Запрос действительно отправлен клиентом только что, а не какой-то плохой MITM взял и заново послал запрос, который уже проходил месяц назад.

Подпись - это обычный хэш от строки, поэтому эту исходную строку подписи надо заставить зависеть от параметров, которые явно бы указывали на подлинность запроса. Обычно это организуется так:

1. Сервер и клиент обмениваются секретным значением. Делается это единожды и **не** по тому каналу связи, по которому потом будут идти запросы, обычно он выдается в неавтоматическом режиме в админке сервиса разработчику клиента.
2. Клиент формирует полный запрос, причем не конкретные объекты, представляющие HTTP-запрос, а именно набор параметров - URL, список аргументов, время запроса, необходимые ключи (В данном случае - один секретный), свой айдишник у сервера, **nonce или время отправки запроса** (в этом случае время запроса добавляется обычным аргументом; ниже - подробнее)
3. Клиент сериализует все данные и получает из них хэш и включает аргументом в запрос. Хэш зависит от секретного ключа, времени запроса/nonce и всех параметров запроса - в результате злоумышленник должен знать весь этот набор для создания имитирующего запроса, а с учетом использования времени запроса или nonce он не может просто взять и повторить запрос.
4. Сервер получает запрос, разбивает на аргументы, составляет точно такой же хэш и убеждается в корректности/некорректности запроса. Если запрос корректен, то он выполняется и обратно отправляется ответ.

Таким образом, явной авторизации (авторизовался и забыл) нет - подписывается каждый запрос, а "пароль" не передается никогда.

Что там с датой и nonce: есть уже упомянутый вид атак, называемых replay attack. Допустим, клиент запросил сервер поменять имя какого-нибудь проекта на "аааа", а затем еще раз - на "ббб". Подслушивающая Ева в этом случае может повторить запрос смены имени на "аааа" то количество раз, которое ей покажется достаточным, чтобы насолить серверу и клиенту. Против этого есть два способа борьбы:

1. Клиент включает в запрос (и хэш) время отправки запроса. Сервер проверяет время прихода запроса, и, если время вышло за пределы позволенного временного отрезка (скажем, пяти минут), то сервер инвалидирует запрос и отказывается его выполнять. Подменять в запросе время отправки бессмысленно, т.к. в этом случае не сойдется хэш, и сервер инвалидирует запрос уже на этапе проверки хэша.
2. Сервер выдает клиентам nonce - **n**umber used **once**. В этом случае сервер выдает и запоминает уникальные одноразовые значения для подписи запрослв (те же хэши, например) своим клиентам, после чего, когда приходит запрос, он проверяет наличие такого nonce в своем репозитарии, и если его нет, инвалидирует запрос, а если есть, то этот nonce удаляется из репозитария, и Ева опять не может ни повторить запрос, ни использовать уже использованный nonce. Сервер при этом может не просто хранить nonce, но и запоминать привязку по айпи и дате (хотя на самом деле подменить айпи пакета не составляет особого труда, только вот ответ в этом случае уйдет не тому, кто подменил).

nonce чаще всего используется в том случае, когда клиент - это браузер пользвателя и там сложно говорить об api в классическом смысле; в частности, csrf-token - это nonce, обычно сгененрированный на основе ip пользователя.

Comment: > Обычно создается секретный ключ, который знают только сервис и клиент;

**обычно** создается два секретных ключа и ни одна сторона не знает о секретном ключе другой.

тут вы описали похожее на cram-md5 с подписью закрытым ключом.

Comment: Ева не подслушивает :)

Comment: @eicto, я тут не о диффи-хеллмане, я о стандартном oauth-like подходе. Ева пошло от eavesdropper.

Comment: Ну да в общем то без разницы :) мне кажется вы просто перемудрили. Тут же как - если апи для машин, и ui там очень далеко, то надо делать обычную авторизацию с открытыми ключами (может еще и cert центр завести), а если там юзера, то какие-то пляски на балансе безопасности-удобства.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответы. Только с паролем не совсем понял. Как идентифицировать клиента, у которого есть свои данные профайла в БД. Так чтобы дать возможность ему изменять эти данные. Как я понимаю для вместо пароля у каждого будет свой секретный ключ передаваемый в URL, вместо пароля.

Comment: публичный ключ будет, его будет знать сервер, а секретный будет у него на компе (на то он и секретный, чтобы никому не рассказывать) далее читаем википедию.

Comment: По каким критериям найти в википедии?